# How to avoid repeating query in concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency

For a given request like `/api/user/1`, suppose it will take 10s for querying from db.

So at first there is one request accepted by the server, and the service start to query the db. Then during the query, there maybe some more incoming same requests(all for `/api/user/1`).

How to avoid the later requests query the database? We do not mean cache, we just want to avoid the **exactly same query occur at the same time**.

Is this make any sense? If yes, how to you make that (Take Java or node application as example)?

Comment: The problem was discussed there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299738/synchronise-concurrent-requests-to-share-results-of-a-slow-operation

Comment: Thanks, I have treid to search in google and sf, but I did not found this post. We can close it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ConcurrentHashMap` (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)) which maps route strings like `"/api/user/1"` to a `List` of callbacks taking a single parameter of type `T` (replace `T` with whatever class you use to store request results). Your `request` method will need to use a `Consumer<T>` for the callback. If you are not familiar with `Consumer<T>` you can read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html). It is simply an interface representing a function which takes one parameter of type `T` and which returns nothing.

When a thread wants the result of the request to a route it should call a synchronized method `register` which takes a route as a `String` and a callback and does the following:

It should check if the route is a key in the `Map`. If it isn't, it should add the route as a key to the `Map` with its value being a `List` containing one value, the callback supplied in the parameter, and then it should initiate the request with a callback to a method `resolve` which I will discuss below. If the route was already a key in the `Map` then the callback of the thread should simply be added to the `List` in the `Map` where the route is the key.

The `resolve` function should take the route as a `String` and the request result of type `T`. It should then get the `List` at the route key, remove the route key from `Map`, and finally iterate over all of the callbacks and call them with the request result.

I have written up some code with an example, but I have not tested it.

CallbackHandler.java

```
public abstract class CallbackHandler<T> {
    private QueryRepetitionHandler<T> handler;
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    private T result;

    public CallbackHandler(QueryRepetitionHandler<T> handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
        latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    }

    public void resolve(T result) {
        this.result = result;
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public void request(String route) {
        handler.register(route);
        latch.await();
    }
}
```

QueryRepetitionHandler.java

```
public abstract class QueryRepetitionHandler<T> {
    private Map<String, List<CallbackHandler<T>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    protected abstract void request(String route, Consumer<T> consumer);

    public synchronized void register(String route, CallbackHandler<T> handler) {
        if (map.containsKey(route)) {
            map.get(route).add(callback);
        } else {
            List<CallbackHandler<T>> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(callback);
            map.put(route, list);
            request(route, result -> resolve(route, result));
        }
    }

    private void resolve(String route, T result) {
        List<Consumer<T>> list = map.remove(route);

        // Sanity check
        if (list != null) {
            list.forEach(handler -> handler.resolve(result));
        }
    }
}
```

You'll want to instantiate one `QueryRepetitionHandler<T>` to be shared by all of your threads. When a thread wants to make a request it should instantiate a `CallbackHandler<T>` using the shared `QueryRepetitionHandler<T>`. Of course, you can't instantiate `QueryRepetitionHandler<T>` without implementing the `request` method. The `request` method should simply make the request and then call the callback provided as a `Consumer<T>`. It should then call the `request` method of `CallbackHandler<T>` with the desired route as a `String` argument. That thread will then be waiting (using `latch.await()`) for the result of the request until `QueryRepetitionHandler<T>` calls its `resolve` method with the result and calls `latch.countDown()`.

Comment: Tha's right, you does not misunderstand me. While I am not sure how to use that since I am not familiar with the function programming in java.

Comment: This is what I tried to use the handler in an interceptor: https://i.imgur.com/gYtVcNBg.png

Comment: I made some changes after thinking about the problem and added a description at the end of the answer regarding how to use the code. Does this clear it up?